# What is the recommended minimum CPU, disk space and memory (RAM) requirements of Ubuntu 64 and 32 bit?

Tags: system-requirements

What is the recommended minimum CPU, disk space and memory (RAM) requirements of Ubuntu 64 and 32 bit 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

700 MHz processor, 512MB of RAM. pretty much the basic high end for a windows 98 computer...

hope this helps, [heres the link to what I found on the system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)